# Get a particular field value from file using commands in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, field

I am using Ubuntu 14.
I want to get field(F1) value From File ( , seprated file )
but the problem is field position is not fix.
and want to use only commands in Linux.

Here I attached Example :

F2=xyz, F3=123, **F1=json**,    F4=format,  F5=331
**F1=csv**, F2=xyz, F3=123,     F4=format,  F5=240 
F2=xyz, F3=123, **F1=xml,**     F4=format,  F5=128 
F2=xyz, F3=123, F4=lang,    **F1=java,**    F5=350 
F2=xyz, **F1=.net**,    F3=123,     F4=lang,    F5=500 
**F1=csv**, F2=xyz, F3=123,     F4=format,  F5=240 
 
F2=xyz, F3=123, **F1=string**,  F4=format,  F5=60 
F2=xyz, F3=123, F4=format,  **F1=byte**,    F5=140

output shold be :

json
csv
xml
java
.net
csv
string
byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What manoj said works, assuming you are giving the correct file path location. You can also use `sed` to truncate characters like:

```
  $ grep -o 'F1=[^,]*' /path/to/file | cut -c4-
  $ grep -o '[^ ]*F1[^ ]*' /path/to/file | sed "s/^F1=\(.*\),$/\1/"
```

Update, This also works on ubuntu - PCRE

```
  $ grep -oP 'F1=\K([^,]*)' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below command

```
grep -o '[^ ]*F1[^ ]*' FILENAME | cut -c4- | rev | cut -c2- | rev
```

Comment: hello Manoj , i tried this command but output is nothing. can u tell another command ..

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the parts you don't want.

```
sed 's/^\(.*, \)\?F1=//;s/, .*//' file
```

The first expression substitutes everything before the F1= marker, and the second everything after the value. I assume traditional Linux `sed` syntax (grouping parentheses and `?` quantifier need a backslash); if you are on a  different platform, adapt accordingly.